# Updating hot score in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I am implementing a system that allows users to post comments. The comments can be sorted by a score, which is based on a time-decay algorithm (e.g., Reddit hot score), so they must be periodically recomputed.

So the post objects would be:

```
{
    dateCreated: Date,
    upVotes: Number,
    downVotes: Number,
    hotScore: Number,
}
```

And periodically, I need to update hotScore to be hotScore(dateCreated, upVotes, downVotes), where hotScore is a function that computes the hotScore.

What's the most efficient way to do this? As a baseline, I can query each document and send update statements. Ideally, I could send a javascript function to MongoDB?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out you can now use the aggregation pipeline in update operations, so you can either implement the scoring algorithm using the aggregation operators or you can use $function if you're using 4.4. Ironically, even Atlas doesn't provide universal access to 4.4 at this time, so I had to use the aggregation operators- messy but it worked.